# Can't serve PHP file with Nginx + Passenger but can serve PhpMyAdmin

Tags: nginx, passenger

Server: Ubuntu 14.04 with nginx-passenger.

My problem is : I can't show a php file in http://www.domain.com/prueba/ but phpmyadmin works in http://www.domain.com/phpmyadmin/ and my rails server is working correctly in http://www.domain.com.

But I want to have a rails server and use php too.

I already configured nginx with passenger to serve phpmyadmin page in

```
 location /phpmyadmin/ {
  root /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin;
  index index.php index.html index.html;
  passenger_enabled off;
}
```

And everything works well but when I want to serve a php file `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in the folder `/var/www/html/prueba` named `index.php`, it says 
*404 not found* in the page but the error is not logged in the nginx log, and everything is configured well.

```
location /prueba/ {
 root /var/www/html;
 index index.php;
 passenger_enabled off;
}
```

What could be the error?

Here's my full config file.

```
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

location / {
 root /var/www/rails_project/current/public;
 passenger_enabled on;
 passenger_app_env production;
 passenger_ruby /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.2.0/ruby;
 passenger_buffer_response off;
}

location /prueba/ {
 root /var/www/html;
 index index.php;
 passenger_enabled off;
}

 location /phpmyadmin/ {
  root /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin;
  index index.php index.html index.html;
  passenger_enabled off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Comment: Try removing the location block for `/prueba/` and see how that works.  The wildcard location block at the end should serve your .php files.

Comment: And how do i serve the index file in `/var/www/html/prueba`?. If i remove the block then the rails server responds with an error page.
`The page you were looking for doesn't exist.` @steveklein

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just didn't put in the correct path:

```
 location /prueba/ {
 root /var/www/html; << HERE should be /var/www/html/prueba
 index index.php;
 passenger_enabled off;
}
```

Make sure that the file path is correct.

Comment: The 404 error isn't recorded anywhere? It should be in there, maybe you should set the logs more verbose while you're troubleshooting.

Comment: No, the error 404 isn't recorded. I know that it should be in there, but nothing appeared, others erros appear, for example if I write ```http://www.domain.com/prueba/lala.php ``` then the error 404 is logged .

Comment: Try adding index.html to your pages line. If that doesn't work try adding the identical information that is under the /phpmyadmin/ block and see if it will serve the phpmyadmin under the /prueba/ location block.